# BlueStack Android Emulator device not found after running adb root command

Tags: android, shell, adb

I installed bluestacks version 0.10.0 on my PC.

When i run `adb shell` this command work fine,

But when i run `adb root` command and then run `adb shell` command it give `error:device not found`.

If i run `adb kill-server` and then `adb shell` it work fine.

Any Help?

Comment: You can run : adb su to get root permission instead use root command

Comment: `adb root` restarts the daemon on the device. just wait a few seconds before running `adb shell`

Comment: How many seconds? I wait about two minutes but nothing happened!